# Azure CLI: Troubleshooting Issues with Variables in Commands – Unexpected Behavior

Tags: filter, azure-cli, azure-app-configuration, azure-feature-manager

I'm trying to extract information from a text file and store the content in a variable using the Azure CLI command below.

```
file_content=$(cat /home/diwakar/cli.txt)
echo $file_content
```

After running the above command, the following output was obtained (Same content I have cli.txt file):

Output:

**Audience={"Users":["user1","user2","user4","user3"],"Groups":[],"DefaultRolloutPercentage":50}**

When I run the actual command, the variable takes on a different value, leading to an error.

```
az appconfig feature filter update --connection-string $endpoint --feature $featurename --filter-name Microsoft.Targeting --filter-parameters $file_content --yes
```

Below is the error message:

**Filter parameter value must be a JSON escaped string. "{"Users":["user1","user2","user4","user3"],"Groups":[],"DefaultRolloutPercentage":50}" is not a valid JSON object.**

[image]

Comment: Refer to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appconfig/feature/filter?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appconfig-feature-filter-update) for Azure CLI `az appconfig feature filter update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Filter parameter value must be a JSON escaped string.
> "{"Users":["user1","user2","user4","user3"],"Groups":[],"DefaultRolloutPercentage":50}" is not a valid JSON object.

The above error occurred due to the value of the `$file_content` variable is not a valid JSON object. This is because the value of the `$file_content` variable is being interpreted as a string literal, rather than a JSON object.

In my environment, I set the **`cli.txt`** as below:

```
{"Users":["user1","user2","user4","user3"],"Groups":[],"DefaultRolloutPercentage":50}
```

[image]

Using the below command I can able to update the az appconfig feature filter from the text file.

**Command and output:**

```
vexxxre:~$ file_content1=$(cat cli.txt)
venkxxxe:~$ echo "$file_content1"
{"Users":["user1","user2","user4","user3"],"Groups":[],"DefaultRolloutPercentage":50}
venkxxxx:~$ az appconfig feature filter update --connection-string <your-connection-string> --feature <Your-feature-name> --filter-name Microsoft.Targeting --filter-parameters Audience="$file_content1" --yes
This command is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
{
  "name": "Microsoft.Targeting",
  "parameters": {
    "Audience": {
      "DefaultRolloutPercentage": 50,
      "Groups": [],
      "Users": [
        "user1",
        "user2",
        "user4",
        "user3"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[az appconfig feature filter | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appconfig/feature/filter?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appconfig-feature-filter-add-examples)